# Scrollview area

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

In a scrollview I added a few buttons. As you see in the picture, 2 buttons are fully visible and the third one is halfly visible. When I scroll to the right to see third one; 
1- If the scroll is short then it srolls back to the first position. 
2- If the scroll sufficient then it shows the third button's second half, fourth and fifth buttons. 
I can't see the third one fully. How can I set scrollview to scroll and stop as I move it even in a short move?

[image: first position is here]
[image: second position after scroll]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have paging enabled. Disable it on Interface builder (select the scroll view, open the Attribute inspector, and disable "Paging Enabled") or by code

```
[_scrollView setPagingEnabled:NO];
```